# How to expand product of $n$ factors.

Tags: binomial-coefficients, products, multinomial-coefficients

I have a product say 
\begin{equation}
F(a,n,x) = \prod _{j=0}^{n}(1-{a}^{n-2\,j}x)
\end{equation}
I want to expand and hope to have general terms of the coefficients. I did for $n= 2,3,4,5,6,7,8...$ I
see it will be different for $n$ even or $n$ odd. We have
\begin{equation*}
F(a,2,x)= 1-{x}^{3}+ \left( {a}^{2}+1+{a}^{-2} \right) {x}^{2}+ \left( -{a}^{2}-
1-{a}^{-2} \right) x 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation}
F(a,3,x)= 1+{x}^{4}+ \left( -{a}^{3}-a-{a}^{-3}-{a}^{-1} \right) {x}^{3}+
 \left( {a}^{4}+2+{a}^{-2}+{a}^{2}+{a}^{-4} \right) {x}^{2}+ \left( -{
a}^{3}-a-{a}^{-3}-{a}^{-1} \right) x
\end{equation}
The coefficients of $a$ gets more interesting as $n$ grows. I am interested in the coefficient of $a.$ Does anyone know how to expand product of $n$ factors.

Comment: By "coefficients of $a$" do you mean "coefficients of $x^k$ in terms of $a$"?

Comment: @ YiFan yes you can say that.

Comment: There should be a development of this product involving the $a^2$-binomial coefficients. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient).

Comment: @Thanks René Gy

Comment: Apply the [$q$-binomial formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#Examples) $\prod\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} \left(1+q^k t\right) = \sum\limits_{k=0}^n q^{k\left(k-1\right)/2} \dbinom{n}{k}_q t^k$ to $n+1$, $a^n x$ and $a^{-2}$ instead of $n$, $t$ and $q$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When expanding the product $F(a,n,x)$ in terms of $x$ the coefficients of $x^k$ are polynomials $P_{n,k}(a)$ in $a$. Here we expand $F(a,n,x)$ in order to see the coefficients of $a$ in $P_{n,k}(a)$ explicitly.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> F(a,n,x)&=\prod_{j=0}^n\left(1-a^{n-2j}x\right)\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{S\subseteq \{0,1,\ldots,n\}}(-x)^{|S|}a^{n|S|}\prod_{j\in S}a^{-2j}\tag{2}\\
> &=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\sum_{{S\subseteq \{0,1,\ldots,n\}}\atop{|S|=k}}(-x)^{|S|}a^{n|S|}\prod_{j\in S}a^{-2j}\tag{3}\\
> &=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-x)^ka^{nk}\sum_{0\leq j_1<\cdots<j_k\leq n}a^{-2(j_1+\cdots+j_k)}\tag{4}\\
> &=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-x)^ka^{nk}\sum_{l=k(k-1)/2}^{k(2n-k+1)/2}\sum_{{0\leq j_1<\cdots<j_k\leq n}\atop{j_1+\cdots +j_k=l}}a^{-2(j_1+\cdots +j_k)}\tag{5}\\
> &=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^k\sum_{l=k(k-1)/2}^{k(2n-k+1)/2}\left(\sum_{{0\leq j_1<\cdots<j_k\leq n}\atop{j_1+\cdots +j_k=l}}1\right)a^{nk-2l}x^k\tag{6}\\
> &=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}(-1)^k\sum_{l=0}^{k(n-k+1)}
> \left(\sum_{{0\leq j_1<\cdots<j_k\leq n}\atop{j_1+\cdots +j_k=l+k(k-1)/2}}1\right)a^{k(n-k+1)-2l}x^k\tag{7}\\
> &=1+\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\color{blue}{(-1)^k}\sum_{l=0}^{k(n-k+1)}
> \left(\color{blue}{\sum_{{0\leq q_1\leq \cdots\leq q_k\leq n}\atop{q_1+\cdots +q_k=l}}1}\right)a^{k(n-k+1)-2l}x^k\tag{8}\\
> \end{align*}
> The coefficients of $a$ in $P_{n,k}(a)$ are given in (8) as the blue marked sum times $(-1)^k$.
>
> We conclude the absolute value of the coefficient gives the number of **integer partitions** of $l$ into $k$ parts with largest part at most $n$.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we note the product (1) consists of $n+1$ factors and from each factor we choose either $1$ or $-a^{n-2j}x$. We represent each choice as subset $S\subseteq \{0,1,\ldots,n\}$.
- In (3) We reorder the summands according to the size $k$ of $S$. We also extract the term $1$ which represents the case $S=\emptyset$. In this case we have chosen always $1$ from each of the $n+1$ factors.
- In (4) we can factor out $-x$ and $a^n$ and thanks to $k$ we can explicitly write the elements of $S=\{j_1,j_2,\ldots,j_k\}$ for each specific choice.
- In (5) we do again a reordering by organizing the summands according to the sum $j_1+j_2+\cdots+j_k$ of the $k$-tupels.

  We observe the smallest sum comes from the $k$-tupel $(0,1,2,\ldots,k-1)$ which gives $$\sum_{j=0}^k j=k(k-1)/2$$

  while the $k$-tupel with the largest sum is $(n-k+1,n-k+2,\ldots,n)$ which gives \begin{align*}\sum_{j=n-k+1}^n j&=\sum_{j=1}^n j-\sum_{j=1}^{n-k} j=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{(n-k)(n-k+1)}{2}\\
  &=\frac{k(2n-k+1)}{2}.
  \end{align*}
- In (6) we factor out $a^{-2(j_1+\cdots+j_k)}=a^{-2l}$.
- In (7) we shift the index of $l$ to start from $0$.
- In (8) we finally change the index variables $j_t=q_t+t-1, 1\leq t\leq k$. We have
  \begin{align*}
  j_1+j_2+\cdots+j_k&=l+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}\\
  q_1+(q_2+1)+\cdots+(q_k+k-1)&=l+\frac{k(k-1)}{2}\\
  q_1+q_2+\cdots+q_k&=l
  \end{align*}

  This way we get an inequality chain containing $\leq$ symbols only which admits a nice interpretation via partitions.

> **Example $F(a,3,x)$:**
>
> We evaluate the expression (8) for the case $n=3$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{F(a,3,x)}&=
> 1+\sum_{k=1}^4(-1)^k\sum_{l=0}^{k(4-k)}\left(\sum_{{0\leq q_1\leq \cdots\leq q_k\leq 3}\atop{q_1+\cdots +q_k=l}} 1\right)a^{k(4-k)-2l}x^k\\
> &=1-\sum_{l=0}^3\left(\sum_{{0\leq q_1\leq 3}\atop{q_1=l}}1\right)a^{3-2l}x
> +\sum_{l=0}^4\left(\sum_{{0\leq q_1\leq q_2\leq 3}\atop{q_1+q_2=l}} 1\right)a^{4-2l}x^2\\
> &\qquad -\sum_{l=0}^3\left(\sum_{{0\leq q_1\leq q_2\leq q_3\leq 3}\atop{q_1+q_2+q_3=l}} 1\right)a^{3-2l}x^3
> -\sum_{l=0}^0\left(\sum_{{0\leq q_1\leq q_2\leq q_3\leq q_4\leq 3}\atop{q_1+q_2+q_3+q_4=l}} 1\right)a^{-2l}x^4\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=1-\left(a^3+a+a^{-1}+a^{-3}\right)x+\left(a^4+a^2+2+a^{-2}+a^{-4}\right)x^2}\\
> &\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{-\left(a^3+a+a^{-1}+a^{-3}\right)x^3+x^4}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with OPs calculation.

Comment: @ Markus. Thanks for time and effort I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Learner: You're welcome.